# TYPO3 go_maps_ext extension - Google map do not display in the frontend / website

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I am working on a website using TYPO3. I want to display a google map containing the location in my website. I used go_maps_ext extension from TYPO3 repository and followed the instructions from there to install it. I had no problem during installation. But google map donot appear on the frontend / website.

Any ideas regarding this, I am quite new to TYPO3. I already have the API key enabled for maps in my google account and I am using this API key in the root template as following

plugin.tx_gomapsext.settings.apiKey = "My API KEY".

Comment: Did you add the extension in your main typoscript template?

Comment: yes I did add the extension in main typoscript template

Comment: Is there nothing in frontend source code visible? No JavaScript error?

Answer (score 0):

You must have this

```
plugin.tx_gomapsext.settings.apiKey = My API KEY
```

instead of this

```
plugin.tx_gomapsext.settings.apiKey = "My API KEY"
```